# How (practically) to reuse an existing .NET library in MonoTouch

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, code-reuse, csproj

Let's say I've got an existing .NET assembly built in Visual Studio 2010, which is consumed in some other Winforms product. It has no third-party dependencies.

I want to reuse that library directly in a MonoTouch solution.

As it stands, to be able to add a reference to my library from within my MonoTouch UI project, I have to create a new csproj file and create links to all of the source files within it.

This works but is a maintenance burden. There must be a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today you need to rebuild your assemblies. That's because they'll be linked to monotouch BCL (e.g. a different mscorlib.dll) which a superset of the base class libraries (BCL) shipped with Silverlight.

Hopefully newer release of MonoTouch (and Mono, Mono for Android...) will support the new  "portable library" which would make it easier to share compiled binaries across frameworks.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx

Comment: Yup, rebuilding the assemblies I can understand, and not a problem. It's more that I guess I might have expected MonoDevelop to be a bit smarter in this situation. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, you actually can reference a .dll lib built in VS.NET as long as your shared assembly is not referencing any other assemblies that would make it incompatible with monotouch. I currently am doing this on our project. The referenced .dll only has dependencies on `System` and `System.Core` and its basically just a set of POCO's. I'm sure someone with better knowledge can tell you exactly what it would take to make the .dll incompatible. Even using an incompatible API call within `System` or `System.Core` could break it per poupou's answer but if you keep your shared .dll dead simple it should work.

Comment: Referencing a DLL is one thing, but I can't add a project reference to a library project, something about target framework version being wrong. That's what I really want to be able to do...

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. The best you can do is what you're already doing. Creating a new project adding in file links.