# MonoTouch Call RabbitMQ .NET DLL File : throw 'Could not load type' error

Tags: xamarin.ios, rabbitmq

I am a MonoTouch developer, i am writting a project for sending RabbitMQ message to a server, i have a .NET Project ( Using VS 2010) to Call RabbitMQ .NET Client DLL File to send  RabbitMQ message is correct, but When i reference this .NET Client DLL File(RabbitMQ.Client.dll) to MonoTouch iOS Project, and call sending message method,  it throws this error message:

could not load type 'System.configuration.ConfigurationSettings' from assembly 'RabbitMQ.Client'

Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference (binary) desktop assemblies in MonoTouch, you have to rebuild the dll using the MonoTouch BCL.

Just create a new MonoTouch Class Library solution, copy/link to your RabbitMQ source files and then you can use this dll/project instead.

There is some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779046/how-practically-to-reuse-an-existing-net-library-in-monotouch).